# only one string at a time in a method

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a method in a singleton:

```
public void myMethod(String x){
    //do lengthy process on x
}
```

I have three threads calling `myMethod`:

> 1. Thread A, x="word" --> start at 05.00.01pm, finished at 05.00.10pm
> 2. Thread B, x="sentence" --> start at 05.00.01pm, finished at 05.00.08pm
> 3. Thread C, x="word" --> start at 05.00.02pm, finished at ???

as you can see, `Thread C` should wait until `Thread A` completes because `Thread C` is also sending `word`. however, `Thread B` is allowed to execute `myMethod` even before `Thread A` finished because it's sending `sentence` not `word`.

`myMethod` will be called frequently and there are no rules for `parameter x` in `myMethod`, so I don't think saving all possible values for `parameter x` is feasible

FYI : while the string length of "x" param is not limited, the characters are guaranteed to be alphanumeric (a..zA..Z0..9) only, no weird accented character
How do I do this?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the contents of your strings? Characters in the range 0-127 only for instance or the whole of Unicode?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by putting a synchronized block based on the canonical representation of your String inside your method

```
public void myMethod(String x){
   synchronized(x.intern()){
    //do lengthy process on x
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont think string internment is a good idea. there are no rules for the param sent to myMethod, so, there'll be tons of strings and will trigger global GC frequently. myMethod is going to be called frequently

Comment: If it's called so frequently and you're blocking on a lenghty process, I don't think your problem will be string interning. Note also that you don't have a performance problem until you can measure it.

Comment: @JoaEbert He can get a memory problem if he floods the String pool with _a lot_ of Strings.

Comment: In that case he already created a _lot_ of Strings. Note that String interning changed a lot in recent JDK releases. In fact, I'm not sure if this is still just a proposal but  there was the idea of sharing the String's backing storage since its immutable to the Java perspective anyways.

Comment: @JoaEbert he created them, but since they might not be interned, they could be eligible for garbage collection. And yes, there is a lot of "might" and "could" since we don't know enough about OPs application :D.

Comment: Interned Strings are GCd as well. See http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/

Comment: as of now, I dont intern any string. I'm invoking an http call to third party web service using the "x" param, and that's why it's gonna take long. and blocking for a long time for same "x" is acceptable in the app spec.

Comment: @JoaEbert : okay, from your post, string.intern() seems quite interesting now. Will this work with lets say 1 million strings? can anybody give more guidance for this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you need to have a hashmap of objects for make a lock, keyed by the function argument:

```
Map<String,Object> locks=new HashMap<String,Object>();
public void myMethod(String x){
    Object lock;
    synchronized (locks) {
        if ((lock=locks.get(x)) == null) locks.put(x, lock = new Object());
    }
    synchronized (lock) {
        // do your staff
    }
}
```

Update (tested):

```
private Map<String,Object> locks=new HashMap<String,Object>();

public void getLock(String x) {
    for (;;) {
        Object lock;
        synchronized (locks) {
            lock=locks.get(x);
            if (lock == null) {
                locks.put(x, lock=new Object());
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            System.out.printf("Thread-%s locked\n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
public void unLock(String x) {
    synchronized (locks) {
        Object lock=locks.remove(x);
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }       
}

public void myMethod(String x){
    getLock(x);

    System.out.printf("Thread-%s start\n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
    // do your staff
    for (int i=0; i<30; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("Thread-%s running %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(),i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.printf("Thread-%s end\n",Thread.currentThread().getName());

    unLock(x);
}

public void run() {
    myMethod("abc");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Test t = new Test();
    Thread ths[] = new Thread[30];
    for (int i=0; i < ths.length; ++i)
        ths[i]=new Thread(t, String.valueOf(i));

    for (int i=0; i < ths.length; ++i)
        ths[i].start();
}
```

Comment: This looks like a gigantic memory leak.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized. Thinking.. :)

Comment: The first commit I wrote as a quick idea how it can be done. Updated version is working